# Apache httpd request/response logging

Tags: linux, apache

Is there a way to log request (full GET URI, response and POST data and response) content with Apache? I have a bunch of games that communicate with the client side over HTTP, they use different variables and output all sorts of things.

I'd like to push all this content into a database for further processing so I can report game play step by step. Cannot modify the server side game files themselves to log this data, they're too many (thousands).

It's not much data, up to 512 bytes or 1K per of both request and response data.

Can't set up a varnish or squid to do it, I have lots of back-end servers, can't add yet another layer to this, I have a load of stuff happening before the app servers (load balancing, firewall, whatnot).

TIA

Comment: place reverse proxy like nginx

Comment: Surely your application has *some* sort of common file that you can put this logging into? (Hopefully you don't literally mean there are "thousands" of entirely separate scripts involved?!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mod_dumpio will get it into a file.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dumpio.html